# Intellij Idea doesn't see values in .yaml file, but successfully references .properties in @Value

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm using `@Value` annotation in my spring boot application.
If I'm using `application.properties` file then Intellij Idea can go to those values if I <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>-Click them. But it doesn't work if I use `application.yaml`.

Comment: That is a statement, not a question. Please ask a question.

Comment: I reached out to developers and it actually is not supported in any version of idea. There is a feature request for this, but it's still in progress.

Answer (score 2):

i think that you use the community edition and i am not sure but i think this only supports .properties files.

OR what i see is that your file ending is .yml, rename it to .yaml and it should work if you use the ultimate edition

Comment: yes when you change it to yaml it works, but thats not what i wanted. seems that there is no solution at this point